# rspec-sidekiq test case shows job in the wrong queue

Tags: rspec, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-7, rspec-sidekiq

I have an app running on rails 7 with sidekiq & redis.
I have two jobs, a RequestJob, which is configured to be enqueued in "critical", and a PollingJob, created by the RequestJob, which is to be run in the "default" queue.

I am trying to run a simple rspec test to verify that the jobs are enqueued, and they are, but the RequestJob is enqueued in "default".

Here is the RequestJob:

```
class RequestJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :critical

  def perform(scoring)
    # critical stuff here
  end
end
```

Here is my test:

```
it "the request and polling jobs are enqueued" do
      post "/v1/sessions/#{sessions(:one).id}/do_it", headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + retailer_private_token }, params: { session: { session_customer_attributes: { email: customers(:one).email } } }
      expect(PollingJob).to be_processed_in :default
      expect(RequestJob).to be_processed_in :critical
    end
```

Here is what the Rspec console output:

```
Enqueued RequestJob (Job ID: 4893e5b7-be70-48e1-af82-c79babe9ada0) to Test(critical)
```

So far so good, but here is the test result:

```
expected RequestJob to be processed in the "critical" queue but got "default"
```

Comment: Have you added the `critical` queue to the sidekiq config? https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Comment: yes i did! my sidekiq.yml :
`:queues:
  - critical
  - default`